# Установка nginx

Tags: nginx, debian, vesta

ДД! 
есть виртуальный сервер на debian 7.
панель управления vesta cp.
хотел установить php 7 на него, но в ходе установки удалился nginx, exim4.

```
apt-get install nginx
```

пишу эту команду и выдает ошибку

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    nginx : Depends: nginx-full (>= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed or
>                     nginx-light (>= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed or
>                     nginx-extras (>= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed
>            Depends: nginx-full (< 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
>                     nginx-light (< 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed or
>                     nginx-extras (< 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2.1~) but it is not going to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте выполнить полную установку nginx

`apt-get install nginx-full`

либо установить nginx-extras

`apt-get install nginx-extras`

Comment: >Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Comment: >The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-extras : >Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed
                >Depends: libnginx-mod-http-geoip (= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed
                >Depends: libnginx-mod-http-image-filter (= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed
                installed
>E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: >Depends: libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter (= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed
                >Depends: libnginx-mod-mail (= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed
                >Depends: libnginx-mod-stream (= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: >Depends: libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam (= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed
                >Depends: libnginx-mod-http-lua (= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed
                >Depends: libnginx-mod-http-perl (= 1.10.2-2~dotdeb+8.2) but it is not going to be installed
                >Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.13-38+deb7u10 is to be installed
                >Depends: libpcre3 (>= 1:8.35) but it is not going to be

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get update

apt-get install nginx
```

А вообще тебе в консоли же пишет, что тебе необходимо установить такие-то пакеты:
nginx-common, libnginx-mod-http-geoip, libnginx-mod-http-image-filter и т.д.

Comment: пробовал не помогает. там рекурсивно выдает ошибки